# Mysql date less than week operation

Tags: mysql, sql, date

Suppose you have two datetime values, **`date_a`** and **`date_b`**

What expression evaluates to true if `date_a` occurs *within or less* than the *calendar week* of `date_b`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [MySQL's `week()` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week).

Example:

```
mysql> create table daten (a date, b date);
mysql> insert into daten values ('2011-04-14', '2011-04-12');
mysql> insert into daten values ('2011-04-14', '2011-04-22');

mysql> select * from daten where (week(a)=week(b) and year(a)=year(b)) or a<b;
+------------+------------+
| a          | b          |
+------------+------------+
| 2011-04-14 | 2011-04-12 |
+------------+------------+
```

This will give you all records with a in the same or an earlier calendar week than b. Note that `week(a)<=week(b)` would not work, because weeks start again each year.

*Note:* There is more than one convention for counting calendar weeks (week starts on Sunday or on Monday, different start of first week of the year). You can pass an optional second parameter "mode" to `week()` to tell it which convention to use; see the docs. Of course for this problem only the start day of the week matters, not what the first week of the year is.

Comment: week(a)=week(b) will mess up if the dates span multiple years

Answer (score 1):

A more brute force method:

```
Select ...
From DateValues
Where date_a >= Date_Add( date_b, Interval -DayOfWeek( date_b ) + 1 Day )
    And date_a <= Date_Add( date_b, Interval -DayOfWeek( date_b ) + 7 Day )
```